# Hotspot or USB tethering not functioning on Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 Pro on Android 11

Tags: connection-issues, wifi-hotspot, usb-tethering, redmi

My Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 Pro on Android 11 was updated to the latest MIUI. When I activate the hotspot or USB tethering, when connecting from my PC or other phones, it does not let me surf or use the internet.

In my Windows 10, I enter the IP config command and everything comes out well configured, either by tethering or by hotspot, but I do not navigate in any way.

Help, please.

Comment: Some SIM providers don't allow tethering or otherwise provide tethering as an additional feature (similar issue: [Mobile hotspot working but no data with lollipop 5.1](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/118814/44325)).

Comment: Do you have double SIMs?  Does your telco allow tethering?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Find My Device is not on. I had same issue connecting to my tablet from my Galaxy J2 Android.

Answer (score 0):

When my Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 Pro, on MIUI 14, had the same behavior (hotspot allows other devices to connect to it but the internet doesn't work on those devices), I changed the sim card from sim2 to sim1 position in the drawer and now it works as expected.

Comment: The OP hasnt indicated that they have dual SIMs